# Tensorboard: How to view model summary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

**Problem Statement**

- Run a model with multiple configurations and compare graphs. Based on plot analysis, select a configuration.

In the above statement, I am able to plot multiple runs of the model with their names. Now I need Tensorboard to show configuration/summary of the model against each run as well.

**Question is**
Would it be possible to view the model summary in the Tensorboard for corresponding to each run of the model?

[image: This is how tensorboard looks like]

Comment: If anyone is looking to visualize PyTorch model in tensorboard, this post might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72526515/6117565

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`text`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/text) summary with the model summary, something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Get model summary as a string
def get_summary_str(model):
    lines = []
    model.summary(print_fn=lines.append)
    # Add initial spaces to avoid markdown formatting in TensorBoard
    return '    ' + '\n    '.join(lines)

# Write a string to TensorBoard (1.x)
def write_string_summary_v1(writer, s):
    with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
        summary = tf.summary.text('Model configuration', tf.constant(s))
        writer.add_summary(sess.run(summary))

# Write a string to TensorBoard (2.x)
def write_string_summary_v2(writer, s):
    with writer.as_default():
        tf.summary.text('Model configuration', s, step=0)

# Model 1
inp1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,))
out1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100)(inp1)
model1 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp1, outputs=out1)
# Model 2
inp2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,))
out2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200)(inp2)
out2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100)(out2)
model2 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp2, outputs=out2)
# Write model summaries to TensorBoard (1.x)
with tf.summary.FileWriter('log/model1') as writer1:
    write_string_summary_v1(writer1, get_summary_str(model1))
with tf.summary.FileWriter('log/model2') as writer2:
    write_string_summary_v1(writer2, get_summary_str(model2))
# Write model summaries to TensorBoard (2.x)
writer1 = tf.summary.create_file_writer('log/model1')
write_string_summary_v2(writer1, get_summary_str(model1))
writer2 = tf.summary.create_file_writer('log/model2')
write_string_summary_v2(writer2, get_summary_str(model2))
```

For some reason, writing the summary in 2.0 works fine, but 2.0 TensorBoard fails when I try to show it, which I think is a bug. However, TensorBoard 1.15 shows it just fine (written from either version). The result would look something like this:

[image: TensorBoard result]