# is there any way to see total number of parameters in tensorboard graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a graph in Tensor flow and I would like to see the total number of trainable parameter it has in Tensor board.

I have trained the model and saved it, and then i launch tensor board where i can see details of training, graph, etc... but I do not see the total number of parameters. Is there any way to do this?

I have seen posts where they count using `tf.trainable_variables()`, but isn't there any easier way in tensor board?

Answer (score 0):

You can just write the model summary using [tf.summary.text](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/text) and display it in tensorboard, where you can see all the details in model summary like trainable & non trainable parameters etc.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58642687/tensorboard-how-to-view-model-summary) answer for some more reference.